# Parallel processing in standalone Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I am developing a Spark application to analyse some big tables stored in RDBs, and have some issues making spark utilise our hardware.

Our current system architecture is the below.

- One server containing Spark and all databases
- Spark using standalone mode and hosted inside Docker
- Spark application (client+server) written in Java, and also inside Docker
- Oracle for source data, via Spark SQL
- Postgres for calculated data, mainly via JDBC
- Main workload in Spark SQL (without any performance hints)

So far I have not been able to make use of more than one hardware core.
Below are the configurations that I have tried.

- Increase the number of executors
- Increase the number of cores per executor
- Enable the caching and partition parameters

How can I make Spark use more cores?
Thanks.

Comment: Please share some code example and a snippet from your configurations